# Laravel, how to use api routes for multi-tenant app

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman, multi-tenant

I am trying to work with API routes on an multi tenant web app on Laravel. I also have installed tenancyforlaravel package. I have configured successfully API routes and web based routes for central domains, but I am a bit stuck on API routes for tenant. And that is my problem, I have created a new file under `/routes/tenant/api.php` and then called it on `routes/tenant.php`.

```
//api.php
Route::prefix('api/v2')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
        // Protected API routes go here
        
        // Example protected route
        Route::get('/user', function () {
            return auth()->user();
        });
    });
});
```

on the tenant.php I have created this route , so i can generate an api key for authenticated user from web based app

```
    Route::get('/user/issue-token', [UserController::class, 'issueAPIToken'])->name('users.api.token');

    //Controller
    public function issueToken()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    }
```

After i get the token i try to auth on postman like this

```
#url: http://foo.localhost:8000/api/v2/user
#headers
#[{Accept","value":"application/json"}]
#[{Authorization","value":"Bearer 5|jhA...."}]
```

But I am getting this message `"message": "Unauthenticated."`.

This does not work only for tenants, because for the central users it works. Does anyone have any idea how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Does your User class contain `use HasApiTokens` trait? Make sure it's imported from `Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens`

Comment: Yes, i have `HasApiTokens` this on my `users.php` Models. Should i add this on `tenant.php`Models?

Comment: I think the problem is on the tenant conf beacouse when i hit the url `foo.localhost:8000/api/v2/user` on browser told me url does not exist and if i remove `foo` redirect me to home. So i think is not working with tenant conf